# JSON Schema "oneOf" each?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Is it possible to make a JSON Schema which validates that an array contains at least 1 instance of three non-overlapping types. A simple example is an array of numbers of any length that contains at least one 1, one 2, and one 3.

I can't use `allOf` because that will validate that every number in the array is a 1, 2, and 3 - which no number can be

I can't use `anyOf` because then I can have an array with only one element

I can't use `oneOf` because, again, I can have an array with one number

(...also I'm unclear if I should be working with the `contains` key or inside the `items` key)

What I'm looking for is a way to say *"one of each"* of these items. Is it possible with JSON Schema?

---

Here's a broken example with `oneOf`

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "numbers": {
            "type": "array",
            "contains": {
                "oneOf": [
                    {
                        "const": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "const": 2
                    },
                    {
                        "const": 3
                    }
                ]
            },
            "items": {
                "type": "number"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[1] – Should NOT validate

[1,2] - Should NOT validate

[1,2,3] - SHOULD validate

[1,2,3,4] - SHOULD validate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the `contains` inside of an `allOf`:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "numbers": {
            "type": "array",
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "contains": {
                        "const": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "contains": {
                        "const": 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    "contains": {
                        "const": 3
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}``
```